# get click inside of container in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-layout

```dart
Stack(
    children: <Widget>[
        getChartView(widget.globalData.chartSelectValue),
        Container(
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
                border: Border.all(
                    color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), // <--- border color
                    width: 10.0,
                ),
            ),
            width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
            height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 280,
        )
    ],
),
```

I want a click in getChartView() but the container is between click and chartview can any one help me?

Comment: try [GestureDetector](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yeah i got my answer. by me. this not a good solution but it's full fill my need for now :)

```
Stack(
                children: <Widget>[
                getChartView(widget.globalData.chartSelectValue),
                Container(
                  decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                    border: Border.all(
                      color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), //                   <--- border color
                      width: 10.0,
                    ),
                  ),
                  width: 10,
                  height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 260,
                ),
                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), //                   <--- border color
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: 10,
                      height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 260,
                    ),
                  ),

                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), //                   <--- border color
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                  ),

                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.topCenter,
                    child: Container(
                      decoration:  BoxDecoration(
                        border: Border.all(
                          color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), //  <--- border color
                          width: 10.0,
                        ),
                      ),
                      width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
                      height: 10,
                    ),
                  ),

                  Align(
                    alignment: Alignment.bottomRight,
                    child: Container(
                      alignment: Alignment.center,
                      color: Colors.transparent,
                      width: 85,
                      height: 35,
                      child: Image.asset(
                        "assets/img/ic_logo.png",
                        width: 20.0,
                        height: 20.0,
                        alignment: Alignment.center,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ),
              ],),
```

Answer (score 1):

```
Stack(
  children: <Widget>[
    GestureDetector(
      child: Container(
        decoration:  BoxDecoration(
          border: Border.all(
            color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), 
            width: 10.0,
          ),
        ),
        width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
        height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 280,
      ),
      onTap: ()
      {
        getChartView(widget.globalData.chartSelectValue);
      },
    )
  ],
),
```

Comment: i think yo didnt get my question exactly. i have to widget inside stack >> both size same, i want just frame arround getChartView().

Comment: you want to implement `getChartView(widget.globalData.chartSelectValue)` this method, this will be return a widget, am i correct?

Answer (score 0):

Well you may need to check your hierarchy, the way your view are rendered on top of each other cause your are using a stack. Another view might be getting the impulse instead of your getChartView(....)

Answer (score -1):

Or you can use InkWell, which will handle the tap events and also animate the action.

```
InkWell(
  onTap: () {
    getChartView(widget.globalData.chartSelectValue);
  },
  child: Container(
    decoration:  BoxDecoration(
      border: Border.all(
        color: HexColor("#0C1C3B"), 
        width: 10.0,
      ),
    ),
    width: MediaQuery.of(context).size.width,
    height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height - 280,
  ),
 ),
```

Comment: thanks for ur time.
i want a just frame around the getChartView.